# xubuntu firefox(FF) start from cli (command line) vs start from gui (menu option) proxy & env differences

Tags: firefox, proxy, command-line-interface, environment

background: I have a proxy: "myproxy".
I start my machine with /etc/profile.d/myproxy.sh:

```
export http_proxy=myproxy
export https_proxy=myproxy
\EOF
```

I go somewhere that can't reach this proxy, so I unset it...

```
me@hostname:~$ unset http_proxy
me@hostname:~$ unset https_proxy
```

now if I initialize Firefox from cli (the one I ran unset in), it works fine. It picks up that I've unset the proxy. However, if I start it from the start menu (the mouse in a blue circle) as either "Web Browser" or search for it and click:
It doesn't appear to work.

OK. so maybe it's profile.d shenanigans.

```
#export http_proxy=myproxy
#export https_proxy=myproxy
\EOF
```

and

```
me@hostname:~$ source /etc/profile.d/myproxy.sh
```

...And same result...
When I start up a new terminal, the env vars for http_proxy and https_proxy are still there
...shouldn't they go away? I sourced /etc/profile.d/myproxy.sh

I'm assuming this is why FF from the gui is not working for me.
What am I missing? 
Why does the env variable stay when i start up a new terminal?